# ##[error]Error: /usr/bin/xcodebuild failed with return code: 65 while creating react native ios pipeline

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, azure-devops, podfile

These are the errors I'm getting in xcode build when I try to create CI pipeline for IOS react native:

1. /Users/runner/work/1/s/node_modules/react-native-cashfree-pg-sdk/ios/CashfreePgApi-Bridging-Header.h:1:9:
   'React/RCTBridgeModule.h' file not found
   #import <React/RCTBridgeModule.h>
2. error: failed to emit precompiled header
   '/Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CashfreePgApi-cxepqieabxscabamwybllnvrmoxw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PrecompiledHeaders/CashfreePgApi-Bridging-Header-swift_QBU1IX81MTNU-clang_38LLOP6JLEB2G.pch'
   for bridging header
   /Users/runner/work/1/s/node_modules/react-native-cashfree-pg-sdk/ios/CashfreePgApi-Bridging-Header.h
3. error: generate-pch command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see
   invocation)
4. error: generate-pch command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see
   invocation)

5./Users/runner/work/1/s/node_modules/react-native-cashfree-pg-sdk/ios/CashfreePgApi-Bridging-Header.h:1:9: 'React/RCTBridgeModule.h' file not found

#import <React/RCTBridgeModule.h>

6. error: failed to emit precompiled header
   '/Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CashfreePgApi-cxepqieabxscabamwybllnvrmoxw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PrecompiledHeaders/CashfreePgApi-Bridging-Header-swift_2NTBLPEWKMQVG-clang_33EQLJXKHECM6.pch'
   for bridging header
   /Users/runner/work/1/s/node_modules/react-native-cashfree-pg-sdk/ios/CashfreePgApi-Bridging-Header.h

The following build commands failed:

PrecompileSwiftBridgingHeader normal armv7 (in target 'CashfreePgApi' from project 'CashfreePgApi')

CompileSwiftSources normal armv7 com.apple.xcode.tools.swift.compiler (in target 'CashfreePgApi' from project 'CashfreePgApi')

CompileSwiftSources normal arm64 com.apple.xcode.tools.swift.compiler (in target 'CashfreePgApi' from project 'CashfreePgApi')

PrecompileSwiftBridgingHeader normal arm64 (in target 'CashfreePgApi' from project 'CashfreePgApi') (4 failures)